# How to generate Concurrency exceptions in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql-server, concurrency, entity-framework-6

Switching from a mono webserver to a webfarm, I need to re-implement a business critical feature to make it compatible with the webfarm. The code used to be something like:

```
private static readonly Object lockToken = new Object();
public void ChangeState(Foo bar)
{
    lock (lockToken)
    {
        // Change state logic
        
        /*
         *Some code
         */

        Context.Entities.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I know I can't keep the lock and must switch to [application-managed concurrency tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency?tabs=data-annotations#application-managed-concurrency-tokens). Before doing that, and to make sure the implementation is correct I'd like to break my own code and make it throw reals `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` (ie: I want it to be thrown by the framework, not from my code). I tried using this code:

```
Parallel.For(0, 100, y =>
{
    Parallel.ForEach(objects, x =>
    {
        try
        {
            service.ChangeState(new Foo(x));
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException duce)
        {
            count++;
            LogManager.Log.Error("Concurrency Error", duce);
        }
    });
});
```

But I can't make it to happen.

The project is in .NET 4.8 / EF 6 / SQL Server 2016

Comment: See [this](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/handle-concurrency-in-entity-framework.aspx) and [this](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/concurrencycheck-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx) for examples.

Comment: That's an implementation proposition, not how to make my application fail. I need to make it fail in order to make the the implementation works like a charm @GoodNightNerdPride

Comment: Side note: why do you have parallel calls that subsequently are serialized by the lock? You should use a regular `foreach` because you have to prevent concurrent access to the `Context` instance anyway. That said, try inserting an [`ExecuteUpdate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-updating?tabs=ef7#use-executeupdate-and-executedelete-when-relevant) somewhere in the code after you fetched data from the database. It bypasses the change tracker (it's like running a raw SQL statement).

Comment: I'm afraid the question is misleading, I'm not looking for implementation clues (but thanks), I'm looking for a way to test if the implementation that I'll do later is robust, like in a TTD approach @GertArnold

Comment: I understand, but what I mean is that as long as you have one service instance you'll break your code by parallel access to the Context, but not by raising a `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`. To raise that exception you must update the db record "behind EF's back" while it is being processed in memory, before it is saved.

Comment: Glad you rephrase it, I understand way better what you meant. I'll give it a go, thanks!

Comment: The examples there show how to provoke (and handle) a concurrency exception.